# default parameter class method

Tags: programming

I have this function (which works fine):

```
String Esper::rtcTimeString() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  char buf[] = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss";
  return now.toString(buf);
}
```

I'd like to have a default value of "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss" but also pass an argument to a parameter such as "MM/DD/YYYY" if I want to override this default behavior.

Typically, in the definitions .h file I would do something like:

```
String rtcTimeString(char ts[] = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss");
```

and subsequently in the .cpp:

```
String Esper::rtcTimeString(char ts[]) {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  return now.toString(ts);
}
```

However that results in the same returned time string every time.

e.g.

```
1/6/2020 12:01:12
1/6/2020 12:01:12
1/6/2020 12:01:12
```

How can I implement a parameter such that the functionality is the same as in the first code block?

Comment: I would expected char ts[] to be passed as reference (you could change the argument into char* but I doubt it will improve ... What I suggest is to use a PC compiler (e.g. free Visual Studio 2019 C++) and use the internal debugger to see what actually is passed and exactly where it goes wrong. Than move the corrected code back to Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass an array of characters as an argument (implicit or not)
to a function. When you write

```cpp
String rtcTimeString(char ts[] = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss");
```

The array notation is implicitly converted to a pointer. The line above
is then equivalent to:

```cpp
String rtcTimeString(char *ts = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss");
```

And this is incorrect: you are initializing a pointer to *modifiable*
characters using the address of an array of *constant* characters. The
compiler should have warned you about this... if you enabled compiler
warnings. The correct prototype should be

```cpp
string rtcTimeString(const char* ts = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss");
```

But then you cannot pass this pointer to `DateTime::toString()`, as this
method expects the template string to live in a buffer it can overwrite:
that's where it will write the formatted string.

I suggest this solution:

```cpp
string rtcTimeString(const char* ts = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss") {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    char buf[strlen(ts)+1];  // allocate a fresh buffer
    strcpy(buf, ts);         // copy the template there
    return now.toString(buf);
}
```

Comment: Well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This basic C++ (and GIYF).

What about

```
String Esper::rtcTimeString(std::string dateTimeForamt = "MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss")
{
  DateTime now = rtc.now();

  return now.toString(dateTimeForamt );
}
```

See, for instance, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749471/default-string-arguments). Hope this helps :-)